# How can I change the background color of ggplot2 according to hours?

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2, background

I would like to change the background color of ggplot2 depending on the time of day (Day/Night). The idea is to plot a continuous x-axis with the hour, allowing us to see two days in the same x-axis ("1", "3"). I've tried many options and seen tutorials but I can't put the same x-axis for both days, with a grey background when 12:00 PM to 12:00 AM (night) and white when 12:00 AM to 12:00 PM (day). I hope that is clear... I would appreciate any help!

#### To change a 12h

```
Sys.timezone()
Sys.time()
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "en_US.UTF-8") 

hour <- c("01:10:00","23:10:00","19:30:00","10:00:00","14:22:00","15:56:00",
          "17:12:00","09:10:00","11:45:00","21:51:00")
tipe <- c("me","cp","cp","cp","me","cp","me","cp","me","me")
value <- c(4.5,2.3,0.5,7.2,4.9,3.2,6.1,1.6,0.5,2.3)
day <- c("1","1","1","1","1","3","3","3","3","3")


df1 <- tibble::tibble(tipe=tipe,
                     hour=hour,
                     value=value,
                     day=day)

df1$hour <- as.POSIXct(df1$hour,format='%H:%M:%S')


#The graphic
ggplot(df1, aes(x = hour, 
                   y = value, 
                   group = tipe)) +
  #facet_wrap(~day, ncol = 2)+
  geom_line(aes(color = factor(tipe))) +
  theme_classic()+
  scale_x_datetime(date_labels = ("%I:%M %p"),
                   timezone = "GMT", 
                   date_breaks = "6 hours",
                   limits = as.POSIXct(c("2023-04-18 00:00","2023-04-18 23:59")),
                   expand = c(0,0))+
  geom_rect((aes(xmin=as.POSIXct("2023-04-18 12:00"), xmax=as.POSIXct("2023-04-18 23:59"), 
                 ymin=-Inf, ymax=max(Inf))),alpha=0.05)
```

I also tried with `facet_wrap` and that is the correct format but with a continuous x-axis for both days...

The result

[image]

Comment: As you are setting the `timezone="GMT"` for the x scale perhaps you want `as.POSIXct(..., tz = "GMT")` to convert to your datetimes to the same timezone.